# Negate boost range filtered adaptor

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, boost-range

Is it possible/achievable to negate a boost filtered adaptor, e.g.

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for(auto i : v | !filtered(is_even))
    std::cout << i << std::endl; // prints 1,3,5
```

instead of doing the negation inside the lambda expression?

**Motivation:** I work a lot with filtered and lambda functions, however when I use a filter more than once I usually refactor it into a custom filter, e.g.

```
for(auto i : v | even) // note: my filters are more complex than even.
    std::cout << i << std::endl; // prints 2,4
```

Right now when I need the negation I am building a custom filter for them, e.g.

```
for(auto i : v | not_even)
    std::cout << i << std::endl; // prints 1,2,3
```

but I would find it nicer to just be able to negate a filter, e.g.

```
for(auto i : v | !even)
    std::cout << i << std::endl; // prints 1,2,3
```

Comment: change it to `return i % 2 != 0;` instead since it's easier?

Comment: the question explicitly aks for not having to do it inside the lambda expression, i'll add a motivation to the question.

Comment: You edited your question after the comment was posted.

Comment: Sorry for that! I truly thought the remark about not doing it inside the lambda was in the original question. I've added a motivation to the question to put things into context. I hope the intent is now clear. Thanks!

Comment: Going to play devil's advocate again. Why not just do `for(auto& i : v | filtered(!is_even))`? I actually think that's the cleanest solution I can see.

Comment: Might sound silly but I wanted to save some typing and not write filtered every time...

Comment: You just need to implement `operator!` on your adaptor type, such that it returns a negated form of itself. A simple matter of programming.

Comment: @JonathanWakely try it. Not easy to do generically

Comment: like I said, it's a [simple matter of programming](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/S/SMOP.html)

Comment: @JonathanWakely oh lol. That explains. Anyways, I've done a bit of simple programming - it might be enough for the OP

Comment: I would also recommend negating the predicate, not the filter adaptor, as long as there is still a concise way of writing new adaptors. I.e. I think `const auto not_even = filter(not_(even));` is really as clear at it can get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what I came up with on short notice:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/functional.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace boost { 
    namespace range_detail { 

        template <typename T>
            auto operator!(filter_holder<T> const& f) -> decltype(adaptors::filtered(boost::not1(f.val)))
            {
                return adaptors::filtered(boost::not1(f.val));
            }
    }
}

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::adaptors;
    int const v[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    std::function<bool(int)> ll = [](int i){return 0 == (i%2);}; // WORKS
    // bool(*ll)(int) = [](int i){return 0 == (i%2);};           // WORKS
    // auto ll = [](int i){return 0 == (i%2);};                  // not yet

    auto even = filtered(ll);

    for (auto i : v | !even)
    {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
}
```

See it live on **[liveworkspace.org](http://liveworkspace.org/code/IDDkJ%245)**

Note that it currently handles predicates of the form `function pointer` and `std::function<...>`, but not naked lambdas yet (on GCC 4.7.2)

Comment: Great! Your answer just made me take a look at <functional>, i guess std::not1 would work too. It has been really instructive. Shouldn't I have a bad feeling about putting stuff into detail namespaces of boost?

Comment: generally, yeah, it's  not the explicitely documented interface. 
I'd prefer to go with @LucDanton's remark and just invert the _predicate_ instead of the filter (makes more sense too). _[
In this particular instance though, I think you're operating on a semi-stable 'line' that serves extension of Boost Range (at least documented by convention) so it's not so bad.]_

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't excactly answer the question, because it doesn't negate the filter, but only the **predicate**. I'm still posting this, because searching for the solution brought this question up as the first result.

Compared to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14771272/7571258), this has the advantage that we don't need to add custom code to `namespace boost::range_detail`.

## C++17 Solution

The function [`std::not_fn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not_fn) can be used to create a negated predicate.

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct is_even
{
    bool operator()( int x ) const { return x % 2 == 0; }
};

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::adaptors;
    int const v[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    for( auto i : v | filtered( std::not_fn( is_even{} ) ) )
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4889957141d665b1)

## C++11, C++14 Solution

The function [`std::not1`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not1) can be used to create a negated predicate. It has the additional requirement, that the predicate must define a member type, `argument_type` which has the same type as the predicates `operator()` parameter.

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct is_even
{
    using argument_type = int;
    bool operator()( int x ) const { return x % 2 == 0; }
};

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::adaptors;
    int const v[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    for( auto i : v | filtered( std::not1( is_even{} ) ) )
    {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46783f053efbf6ba)